# Test json post request with curl

Tags: spring

When testing my spring code with the following curl request, it fails with a http 400 bad request (The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.)

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"ids":[1,2]}'  <someurl>
```

My corresponding Spring controller has a method that looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "someurl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody List<Result> multiple(@RequestBody List<Integer> ids){
  List<Result> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int id : ids){
    // do something with id and add to result list
  }
  return list;
}
```

My url is correct, I'm almost sure my curl request is also correct, so I don't know what's wrong with my code, this is my first POST request, the GET's are all working.

EDIT:
I'm using a linux terminal

Comment: The solution in that post is to add the content-type, that's already set in my curl request (I made a little edit because there was a copy paste error in my curl request here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RequestBody` expects just a JSON array if used to annotate a `List`.  You'll have to do one of two things:

1. Create a type to represent your POST data, with a single `private List<Integer> ids` field.  Change your controller method signature to use that type instead of `List<Integer>`.
2. Change your JSON POST to:

   `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '[1,2]'  <someurl>`

Either solution should work.